# Hangfire with Ninject

Tags: c#, ninject, ioc-container, hangfire

I am attempting to use Hangfire with Ninject.

Here's my problem, my project is layed out like the following:

```
.Sln
    |- Core
    |- Web
```

Now in the `Core` is the Hangfire method:

```
public class Scheduler
{
    public void HangfireIoc()
    {
        BackgroundJob.Enqueue<MovieSaver>(x => x.SaveMovies());
    }
}
```

MovieSaver class in (`Core`):

```
public class MovieSaver
{
    public IMovieApi Api { get; set; }

    public MovieSaver(IMovieApi api)
    {
        Api = api;
    }
   //Other methods
}
```

Startup.cs (In `Web`)

```
public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
{
  var kernal = new StandardKernel();
  GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.UseNinjectActivator(kernal);

  app.UseHangfireDashboard();
  app.UseHangfireServer();
}
```

I have a Bindings class in `Core` for Ninject:

```
public class Bindings : NinjectModule
{
    public override void Load()
    {
        Bind<IMovieApi>().To<MovieApi>();
    }
}
```

But it seems that when Hangfire starts the job I am getting:

```
Ninject.ActivationException

Error activating IMovieApi No matching bindings are available, and the type is not self-bindable.
 Activation path: 2) Injection of dependency IMovieApi into parameter api of constructor of type MovieSaver 
1) Request for MovieSaver Suggestions: 1) Ensure that you have defined a binding for IMovieApi. 
2) If the binding was defined in a module, ensure that the module has been loaded into the kernel. 
3) Ensure you have not accidentally created more than one kernel. 
4) If you are using constructor arguments, ensure that the parameter name matches the constructors parameter name. 
5) If you are using automatic module loading, ensure the search path and filters are correct.
```

I am new to Ninject and IoC containers.

Can anyone helpe?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Bindings` Module is not loaded. Try adding

```
kernel.Load<Bindings>();
```

to Startup.cs' `Configuration` method.

you can also load all `Module`s in an assembly by calling:

```
kernel.Load(someAssembly);
```

For example:

```
kernel.Load(typeof(Startup).Assembly);
```

Answer (score 2):

New Ninject.Web.Common.Bootstrapper().Kernel:

```
public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
    {            

        ConfigureAuth(app);

        GlobalConfiguration.Configuration
            .UseSqlServerStorage("ConnectString");

        GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.UseNinjectActivator(new Ninject.Web.Common.Bootstrapper().Kernel);


        app.UseHangfireDashboard();
        app.UseHangfireServer();

    }
```